# Query a text/keyword field in Elasticsearch that contains at least one item not matching a set

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl

I have a document has a "bag.contents" field (indexed as text with a .keyword derivative) that contains a comma separated list of items contained in it. Below are some samples:

```
`Apple, Apple, Apple`
`Apple, Orange`
`Car, Apple` <--
`Orange`
`Bus`  <--
`Grape, Car`  <--
'Car, Bus`  <--
```

The desired query results should be all documents where there is *at least one* instance of something *other than* 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Grape', as per the arrows above.

I'm sure the DSL is a combination of must and not but after 20 or so iterations it seems very difficult to get Elasticsearch to return the correct result set short of one that doesn't contain any of those 3 things.

It is also worth noting that this field in the original document is a JSON array and Kibana shows it as a single field with the elements as a comma-separated field.  I suspect this may be complicating it.

Answer (score 0):

1 - If it is showing up as single field, probably its not indexed as array - Please make sure document to index is formed properly. i.e, you need it to be

```
{ "contents": ["apple","orange","grape"]}
```

and not

```
{"contents": "apple,orange,grape"}
```

2- Regarding query - if you know all the terms possible while doing query- you can form a term_set query with all other terms but `apple` , `orange` and `grape`. termset query allows to control min matches required ( 1 in your case)

If you dont know all possible terms , may be create a separate field for indexing all other words minus `apple` `orange` and `grape` and query against that field.

Comment: If I look at the document I see the original json representation as your first block demonstrates.  In kibana, when observing the field in the "flat" notation, it is comma-separated but that may be a rendering artifact.

Comment: probably, not sure about kibana rendering

Comment: Is there a way to compare the total number of items in an array, vs the number of matches on a query?  

Is it better/possible to do this in runtime fields?